# show and Interact with SVG in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, clickable-image

I have SVG photo which have css styling and java script to make effects to the photo. i try to use the image in flutter using flutter_svg but the problem is it show only the picture .. my problem i hope css hover style for paths working and can read java script events from flutter

Answer (score 0):

You could try and load the svg in a webview perhaps but considering webview for flutter is in preview stages, it might not have all the functionalities needed.